# how to execute query in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
const status = window.navigator.onLine;
if (status) online()
else offline()

window.addEventListener('online', online);
window.addEventListener('offline', offline);

function online() {
  document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = 'green';
  //here i want execute a query like this-------> ($con,"SELECT * FROM users where online='yes' ");
}

function offline() {
  document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  //here i want execute a query like this-------> ($con,"SELECT * FROM users where online='no' ");
}
```

Comment: You don't directly execute PHP code within JavaScript code.  It sounds like the technology you're looking for is "AJAX", in which the JavaScript code makes an HTTP request to the server, which can be a PHP page that runs whatever code you like.  There are many tutorials and examples to get you started with AJAX in PHP, which can be found using your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

For call a PhP request on javascript you need to use xhr like this.

```js
xhr.open('POST', 'myphp.php', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
          mycallback();
        }
      };
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        myinfo: info,
      }));
```